# How to determine my position using Coriolis effect?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, experimental-physics, reference-frames, coriolis-effect

The [Coriolis effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force) is the effect that causes wind and water and moving objects to curve clockwise in the northen hemisphere and anticlockwise in the southern hemisphere, so how to determine my latitude, longitude precisely  using the Coriolis effect.
 If I have a yo yo, a pen, and a compass, how can I determine my position?

Comment: You could, theoretically, determine your latitude with the Coriolis effect, but it is independent of longitude.

Comment: ok then , how to determine the latitude or my position generally ?

Comment: How about a Foucault pendulum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum.

Comment: i need to know the coriolis way but this one is helpful thank you :) but if you know any way for calculating my position using the coriolis effect that would be great :)

Comment: That is a good way of measuring your latitude, there is no way of getting your longitude with Coriolis.

Comment: A Foucault pendulum *does* measures the Coriolis force

Comment: so the answer is that if the pendulum moves clockwise then i'm in the northern hemisphere otherwise i'm in the southern hemisphere ?

Comment: Could be, or maybe it's the opposite... as an experimentalist I hate thinking too much about that level of detail. I would simply put one up and see what it does. Then I would get myself a vacation in Australia and do it again, "down under". Maybe one stop in Singapore, which is pretty close to the equator. :-)

Comment: hahahahahaa :D  but what if i'm kidnaped and all i have is a yo yo and a pen and a compass how can i determine my position :D

Comment: not available .... what about the other tools can i use the yo yo as the pendulum ?

Comment: You can't McGuyver up a Foucault pendulum of sufficient sensitivity without the direct intervention of an Author, so the kidnapping question is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Focault Pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum), measure the rotation period of the plane of oscillation and compare it with the theoretical value
$$T=\frac{24\, h}{|\sin\lambda|},$$
where $\lambda$ is the latitude. If the precession is clockwise you are in the northern hemisphere, otherwise you are in the southern hemisphere. No precession means you are at the equator line.

Comment: i don't get it , is there any way using the coriolis effect ?

Comment: The Coriolis effect is what makes the Focault Pendulum to rotate its plane of oscillation.

Comment: so if the pendulum moves clockwise i'm in the northern hemisphere and anticlockwise then i'm in the southern hemisphere and when am i at the equator line ?